# Flutter - How to fetch and display pdf from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, listview, pdf

I would like to fetch and display pdf using the ListView.builder that returns column. The pdf is from AWS (cloud file storage). However, the code turns red whenever I try to add await and async. I am still new to this. Do you have any tips on how I can view this pdf maybe in another class?

Fetching data from the database. Works fine.

```
List _babyList = List();

Future<void> getApplicantInfo() async {
AuthService().getRequestorApplicants().then((val) async {
  requestorApplicants.clear();
  _babyList.clear();
  for (var i = 0; i < val.data.length; i++) {
    var temp = val.data[i];
    setState(() {
      _babyList.add(temp['medicalcertificate']);
    });
  }
});
```

Displaying the _babyList files (this whole code gets red.)

```
        : ListView.builder (
            itemCount: _babyList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) async{
              return Padding (
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _babyList[0][index].toString().split('.').last == 'jpg'
                        ? Image.network(_babyList[0][index])
                        : PDFViewer(
                            document: await PDFDocument.fromURL(_babyList[0][index]),
                          ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
```

Dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
advance_pdf_viewer:
```

Here is the value of the _babyList() when I print it.

```
[[https://team-uploads.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/medicalcertificate/THIS-IS-JUST-SAMPLE-DO-NOT-COPY-1.jpg, https://team-uploads.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/medicalcertificate/THIS-IS-JUST-A-SAMPLE-DO-NOT-COPY.pdf]]
```

**(EDITED)** Error message:

```
lib/admin/applicants/applicantsModule.dart:1117:30: Error: The argument type 'Future<Padding> Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int)'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Padding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart').
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) async{
                             ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/xx/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/xx/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Post the error as well.

Comment: Hello, @DarShan I already put the error message on the post. Hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `async` in the `itemBuilder` function.

```dart
The argument type 'Future<Padding> Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int)'.
```

As `itemBuilder` needs a widget, here it is a `Future<Padding>`.

Remove the `async` & use a `FutureBuilder` instead to load your PDF.

```dart
ListView.builder (
  itemCount: _babyList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     return Padding (
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             _babyList[0][index].toString().split('.').last == 'jpg'
             ? Image.network(_babyList[0][index])
             : FutureBuilder(
                 future: PDFDocument.fromURL(_babyList[0][index]),
                 builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                    ? PDFViewer(document: snapshot.data)
                    : new Container(); // maybe a show placeholder / loading widget?
                 });
           ]),
      );
  }),
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but I am getting an error `The getter 'count' was called on null.`